# Evaluate infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \cdot 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We have the infinite series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
It can be shown that this sum converges by using the ratio test. Thanks to sympy, I know the that it converges to $\ln(2)$. But how can I derive this?, Why is the natural logarithm here.

---

In general how can we evaluate:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
$$
For $|x| < 1$

Comment: Note that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{x^n}{n}\implies f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} x^{n-1}$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$, $|x| < 1$ is nothing but the Taylor series of $-\ln(1-x)$. If you want to see why (apart from more elementary ways) you can just write $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \int_0^x t^{n-1}dt = \int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{n-1}dt = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t}dt = -\ln(1-x)$ provided $x \in (0,1)$ and there you can change the order of integration and summation (due to being inside of convergence radius). Similarly for $x \in (-1,0)$ (or just interpret above as integrating over directed intervals).